# Failed to install org.gnome.Platform: Unable to connect to system bus

Tags: linux, debian, gnome, windows-subsystem-for-linux, wsl2

I have WSL 2:

```
wsl -l -v
  NAME                   STATE           VERSION
* Debian                 Running         2
  docker-desktop-data    Stopped         2
  docker-desktop         Stopped         2
```

However I am having a problem installing a GNOME-based app:

```
$ flatpak install flathub com.github.geigi.cozy
Looking for matches…
Required runtime for com.github.geigi.cozy/x86_64/stable (runtime/org.gnome.Platform/x86_64/40) found in remote flathub
Do you want to install it? [Y/n]: Y

com.github.geigi.cozy permissions:
    ipc        network        fallback-x11          pulseaudio            wayland
    x11        dri            file access [1]       dbus access [2]       bus ownership [3]

    [1] host, xdg-run/gvfs, xdg-run/gvfsd
    [2] org.freedesktop.Notifications, org.gtk.vfs.*
    [3] org.mpris.MediaPlayer2.Cozy


        ID                                           Arch           Branch         Remote          Download
 1. [✗] org.gnome.Platform                           x86_64         40             flathub           349.5 MB / 363.9 MB
 2. [ ] org.gnome.Platform.Locale                    x86_64         40             flathub         < 333.8 MB (partial)
 3. [ ] org.freedesktop.Platform.GL.default          x86_64         20.08          flathub         < 106.4 MB
 4. [ ] org.freedesktop.Platform.openh264            x86_64         2.0            flathub           < 1.5 MB
 5. [ ] com.github.geigi.cozy                        x86_64         stable         flathub           < 4.1 MB
 6. [ ] com.github.geigi.cozy.Locale                 x86_64         stable         flathub         < 373.4 kB (partial)

Error: Unable to connect to system bus
error: Failed to install org.gnome.Platform: Unable to connect to system bus
```

What's the current workaround to install GNOME-based apps with WSL 2?

Answer (score 3):

A couple of likely issues that you are facing.  I go into great detail on it in [this Ask Ubuntu answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1366619/1165986), so I'm not going to repeat *everything* here, but at a high level:

##### Issue #1:  Gnome requires Systemd, which WSL doesn't support directly

There are several scripts out there to enable Systemd on WSL.  See [this SO question for some options](https://stackoverflow.com/q/55579342/11810933).

At a basic level, this involves creating a new namespace where Systemd can be PID1, entering that namespace, and then running your apps and commands from inside that namespace.  That's what my AU answer that I linked above covers.  That technique *does* have limitations, though, which is what the more complex scripts such as Genie and WSL2 Hacks attempt to handle.

##### Issue #2:  WSL2 doesn't include GUI app support by default

If you have Windows 11, you can use WSLg, or you can use one of the alternative solutions in [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/61860208/11810933) (or several other questions and answers across the Stack Exchange network).

Comment: Gnome apps does not seem to work with WSLg either

Comment: @cyberquarks That is true. There is still no support for Systemd, so no Gnome apps unless you first hack around that.